# MVC 4 model Binding in KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

Controller Code :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
PersonRepository repo = new PersonRepository();
PersonListModel lstPersons = new PersonListModel();
lstPersons.Persons = repo.GetAllPerson();
return View(lstPersons);
}
```

Actual Javascript Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var personListData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Persons));

var viewModel = {
personsModel : ko.observableArray(personListData)

}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel)

<script/>
```

Result while Debugigng :

```
 var personListData = [
  {"PersonId":324783035204000026,"FirstName":"Gibbbs","BirthDate":"\/Date(1347647400000)\/"},{"PersonId":324126155204000001,"FirstName":"Russel","BirthDate":"\/Date(1347561000000)\/"}];
```

*Question :

1. when the model data get bindinng it will show me person id as : 324783035204000026 but when the binding process get complete it make change into PersonId as : 324783035204000000 and 324126155204000001 to 324126155204000000
2. Date data is also not binding properly.

so what is the main reason behind it ?

please help me if you have any idea about this.

Answer (score 1):

1. The number 324783035204000026 is too large to be accurately represented by JavaScript, so the last two digits are getting dropped. You can fix this by making the `PersonId` property in your `PersonListModel` class a string, rather than a decmial, or whatever it currently is.

   If you cannot modify the `PersonListModel` class, for whatever reason, you should create a new class, called something like `PersonListModelClient`, that has the subset of properties you need for your JavaScript code, and then copy the data from each `PersonListModel` into a new instance of `PersonListModelClient`, then encode them as JSON instead.
2. This is because dates have no standard representation in JSON, so Microsoft invented a format, that looks like `"\/Date(1347647400000)\/"`, where a date is encoded into a string. You have two options: If you just want to display the date to the user,you can use the same approach as before, and change the `BirthDate` property into a string, and do the formatting on the server side using the `DateTime.ToString` method. Alternatively, you can [use the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date/2316066#2316066), which shows how to convert the specially formatted string into a regular JavaScript Date object.